# unable to register device via web page. Page does not follow tutorial

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

In the page below, it specifies that you can register your device in the left hand column of the page, under advanced options:

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/register-device

This is no longer the case, the option is not there. Instead there is a backend option.

Is there any kind of web page to do this action at all?

Would prefer a graphical option to a command line one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. sorted this out.

My thanks to those who looked over this question. Basically I deleted the current projects and started again.  the device model registration is right down (scroll right down to) the bottom of the page on the first screen after you have first created the project.  Apparently you need to not skip this step, or navigate away from this page before you do the device creation.

after that everything went well and is up and running. Thanks again